# Nested Dropdown alternative for User Skills in web

Tags: web, dropdown

I have a searchable dropdown from in which user can add their skills like below :

[image: Dropdown screenshot]

In the example, "Office Software" is main category and items below this are subcategories that user selects to as her skills. But it is hard for user to find all the items by typing in dropdown and add them, so I am looking for an alternative solution that user can easily navigate from categories and select the desired skill.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: How many categories/subcategories/skills there would be? If you have tons of subcategories, a nested dropdown probably wouldn't be an option.

Comment: Why are the users having a hard time finding the items? Do they not know what to type in the search bar? Is the hard part the fact that they can only select one item at a time? Do they want to only see the main categories, and select one to browse through those subcategories?

Comment: @TotZam Yes the hard part is that they can only select on item at a time and finding the items is hard between tons of subcategories. May be seeing the main category and then selecting the subcategories is better approach but I am looking for something different than dropdown.

Comment: @Stefano There are tons of subcategories there and nested dropdown does not meet user needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think Nested Dropdowns are well for Top-Down explores.
you can ignore theme if you find a way to bottom-up explore.

For example in Facebook search or any Whether service, you will Search city by name (bottom-up) not the old way: Country -> Province -> City (Top-Down)